# pngfix jquery, with images

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, pngfix

I use  pngfix from jquery : http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/

Everything it's ok, but i have one big problem. When I turn pngfix, in IE6 .png it is transparent, but images's with are changing , They become bigger. I don't know why ?? And it just in IE6 , in other browsers it is okei.

How Can I fix it ???

Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

If you know the width and height of an image, set it. Fixing pngs on IE6 is a huge pain in the ass, even with the 'hacks'.

```
<img src="images/my_image.png" alt="My image" width="100" height="200" />
```

I believe most of the problems stem from how these plugins use the `filter` property for IE6 and set it to `scale`. Unfortunately, the other option (`crop`) would clip the image.

Comment: but when I have images from css:

background:url('some_img.png') repeat-y;

?

I put width , but also it is different as Firefox :(

Comment: I don't really follow. Is your background being scaled? And, are you saying it looks different in Firefox?